# Programming For Various Screen Sizes in Android

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, android-canvas

I'm using the Canvas and the SurfaceView. I've explicitly mentioned the coordinates for various objects and fonts on the screen. The app runs perfectly on Samsung Galaxy S Advance but the  objects are out of scope on smaller screens such as that of Samsung Galaxy Fit or Pop. How do i make it compatible for all screen sizes and pixel densities.
Using dpis seems out of the question as I'm not using any xml layouts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Supporting to Multiple Screens: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get screen resolution at run time and set pixels according to that.

Comment: If it was strictly due to screen sizes then there should have been some differences in the display on the emulator and an actual S Advance handset, right? But the objects are perfectly placed in both!

Answer (score 0):

According to the developer guidelines it is discouraged to do so (work with explicit coordinates). Please refer to the android design guidelines for how to do it better. If you cannot avoid it, you'll need to take into account the screen size and density and compute your coordinates accordingly.

Comment: I tried doing that too. Get the density factor and multiply it to the coordinates. df = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; but this puts everything in the top left corner of the screen!